# How do I "perfectly" center an object following an SVG path in Anime.js?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, anime.js

I'm moving a 20px square around [a circle path](https://codepen.io/gremo/pen/wvKjrMW) in SVG, using [Anime.js](https://animejs.com/). The square, however, is not perfectly centered in it's circular path:

[image]

```
anime({
    targets: '.square',
    translateX: path('x'),
    translateY: path('y'),
    rotate: path('angle'),
    easing: 'linear',
    duration: 10000,
    loop: true,
});
```

https://codepen.io/gremo/pen/wvKjrMW

I've found similar examples, but **I can't understand the math** for making this work:

- [Here](https://codepen.io/Im0-3/pen/xOQjOQ) the object is centered using top/left/margin (even with negative values)
- [Here](https://codepen.io/juliangarnier/pen/dXNgVB) the object is centered using only top/left (with negative values)

Comment: change `top: -10px;` and `left: -10px` to `.square` css class for centerilize(half of square's width and height)

Comment: Thanks. Source for this tip, or it's just a compensation for element width?

Comment: I think it works for all tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your object (square) is indeed following the path. However, the object is translated based on the first pixel on the top left value (so if you make a `1px x 1px` square, you should see that the square is following the path nicely). That is why the object's top left-hand corner is always sticking to the line. What you want is for the middle section of the object to stick to the line.

Using a statically and manually computed value (50% of the box's original width and height) is plausible (e.g. giving `-10px` to both `top` and `left`). However, you might not want to do this when there are many objects being animated (as you'll need to update all the CSS codes when change happens). Instead, we can use the pseudo-element `::after` on your `.square` and translate it by 50% of its width to the left and 50% of its height to the top. This way, the object's point which will stick to the line is the center part of the square. Now, when you update the width and height of your original `.square` element, you need not update the `top` and `left` value. You can't simply add the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` value to the original `.square` div because it will be animated using Anime.js and the initial transform value will be lost. Getting the computed initial transform value from the JS is tricky.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const path = anime.path('.circle path');

  anime({
    targets: '.square',
    translateX: path('x'),
    translateY: path('y'),
    easing: 'linear',
    duration: 10000,
    loop: true,
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #001f3f;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #b10dc9;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.square::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #f012be;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/animejs@3.2.0/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <svg class="circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path d="M400,250c0,82.84-67.16,150-150,150s-150-67.16-150-150s67.16-150,150-150S400,167.16,400,250z" />
  </svg>
  <span class="square"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I wrote that code as a "simplified" version of my code, involving making another SVG following another SVG path. I got the point.

Comment: As side node, I fixed the problem just computing the SVG width/height via JavaScript, before animating. The setting the style to the correct (absolute) negative positions.

Comment: @gremo Great to know that I could help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To understand the logic add another element with a different width/height to see the reference for each object:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const path = anime.path('.circle path');

  anime({
    targets: '.square',
    translateX:path('x'),
    translateY: path('y'),
    easing: 'linear',
    duration: 10000,
    loop: true,
  });
  anime({
    targets: '.square2',
    translateX: path('x'),
    translateY: path('y'),
    easing: 'linear',
    duration: 10000,
    loop: true,
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #001f3f;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #b10dc9;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #f012be;
}

.square2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/animejs@3.2.0/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <svg class="circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path d="M400,250c0,82.84-67.16,150-150,150s-150-67.16-150-150s67.16-150,150-150S400,167.16,400,250z" />
  </svg>
  <span class="square2"></span>
  <span class="square"></span>
</div>
```

As you can see, the top/left corner is following the path. To avoid this you can either use negative left/top to offset the element and have it centred or consdier a different CSS to make something generic.

I made the element with a 0 dimension and considered a `box-shadw` to create the square shape:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const path = anime.path('.circle path');

  anime({
    targets: '.square',
    translateX:path('x'),
    translateY: path('y'),
    easing: 'linear',
    duration: 10000,
    loop: true,
  });
  anime({
    targets: '.square2',
    translateX: path('x'),
    translateY: path('y'),
    easing: 'linear',
    duration: 10000,
    loop: true,
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #001f3f;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #b10dc9;
}

.square {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 10px #f012be;
}

.square2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 20px blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/animejs@3.2.0/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <svg class="circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path d="M400,250c0,82.84-67.16,150-150,150s-150-67.16-150-150s67.16-150,150-150S400,167.16,400,250z" />
  </svg>
  <span class="square2"></span>
  <span class="square"></span>
</div>
```